# Is union based mysql injection able to read files outside database?

Tags: sql-injection, ctf

Can files outside database which are not part of any tables in database be read via union based SQL injection? For eg

*http://xyz.com/fetch?id=3*
Consider id parameter is used at server side by cursor library to execute mysql query and no sanitisation is being done. Would something  like **3' union select '../../x.py' --** be able to give attacker x.py file which is not part of database?

For better reference to the problem (Flag 0): *https://dev.to/caffiendkitten/hacker101-ctf-photo-gallery-4foi*

Answer (score 1):

SQL Injection can lead to Remote Code Execution in some scenarios. As you can see in [this article](https://medium.com/bugbountywriteup/sql-injection-to-lfi-to-rce-536bed29a862), it is possible to read files from the Operating System, that are "outside the database".

Tools like `sqlmap` can help an attacker spawn reverse shells while performing a similar attack. Once an attacker has a shell, depending on the permissions of the user and if privilege escalation is possible, one can potentially take over a server.

Comment: So it's scenario dependent if union based injection can be used to extend access to files not in database?

Comment: Yes. Most likely the user running the database must have access to the file, otherwise one cannot access it via SQL injection. That's where privilege escalation comes into place, if an attacker can escalate from dbuser to root, the server is entirely compromised, and this attack is feasible through SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible e.g. with the `LOAD_FILE()` function available in both [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) and [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load_file/). However, the statement on both sides of the `UNION` must return the same amount of columns. If there are e.g. four columns before the `UNION` you could use something like:

```
' UNION SELECT 1, load_file('../../x.py'), 3, 4' --
```

Comment: I'm aware of that method. However from reference link in the question, to find Zeroth flag, author didn't use load function and was able to pull main.py by directly union it with wrong id. I'm confused if it's internal behavior of mysql to allow it